# Win64 .pdata required to be a separate COFF section?

Tags: windows, pe, seh, binary-format

It seems that Windows usually finds its support structures inside PEs by looking at the header information (especially OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[]), which means that there is no mandatory mapping between these data blocks and certain COFF sections (even though it is somewhat customary, as with .rsrc). As a consequence the COFF sections and their names tend to be all over the place when an executable has been mangled by a packer, 'protector' or some such.

However, it seems that Windows determines location and size of the .pdata (array of [RUNTIME_FUNCTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft9x1kdx.aspx)) via the .pdata COFF section header. Is that correct?

That would make this section unique in that even the most hare-brained 'protector' would have to emit accurate information under the correct name, or register that information dynamically...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the Windows loader doesn't care about the name of the `.pdata` section. It doesn't find the `RUNTIME_FUNCTION` structs based on the section name, but rather based on the content of `NtHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION]`.

Furthermore, the `RUNTIME_FUNCTION` structs don't need to be in "a separate COFF section".

Comment: Thanks, somehow I missed the Exception Table which used to be empty for x86 PEs. It seems that x64 use of this table was documented in v8 of the PE COFF specification; MSDN currently has version 8.3 for download ([pecoff_v83.docx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx)). Anyway, thanks again! I should have looked more closely at the header info.